# how to implement jquery easily slider in the datalist control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

i doing asp.net and using vb.net.
I have a datalist control which inside it show a product img, description, price

the problem is that i was to show the product another img, so i want to have a small picture below the img, so when click on the picture the img change to another.

i want something similar to this link : http://www.inuboss.com/Invitation%20Card/Birthday%20A3-5.htm

this link they use flash to come out with the effect that i want, but they are not in datalist, so think that i may need to use ajax but which one?

anyone have any sample or example ?

if i was to use the jquery easy slider numeric navigation how am i going to implement onto the datalist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like you search for a some sort of javascript image slider. There are a lot of such plugins those use libraries like jQuery or based on just plain javascript in an Internet. Check for this one based on jQuery for example:  http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider.  Or google for "image slider javascript"

Comment: can it be put in datalist control?